# configure: error: Qtenv cannot find qmake in omnet++ installation

Tags: qt5, omnet++

I'm trying to install omnetpp 5.2.1 on windows 10. But getting an error while doing `./configure` command related to QT environment. I tried changing the `configure.user` file in omnetpp package to change the path of QT but still its not working. Here is the error:

> configure:error: Qtenv cannot find qmake--maybe it is not in the path
>   or has some exotic name (tested names were: qmake qmake-qt5 qmake5)-
>   disabling Qtenv. You can try setting QT_PATH variable in
>   configure.user to a valid location.

Comment: If you're reading this and you're coming from MacOS, make sure you source the setenv script (`$ . setenv`) before running configure (via: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/omnetpp/z8Zk0Gia2bA/PLb_9-C0DwAJ)

Answer (score 4):

qt5 might not be installed.
`sudo apt install qt5-default` worked for me while installing on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ comes with all dependencies bundled. As long as you have executed the mingwenv.cmd and running from that shell, qmake should be available in the path (in tools/win64/mingw64/bin). Check if qmake.exe is present there. If not, make sure that ZIP file you have downloaded is intact. Standard windows unzip may fail on certain systems...

Comment: Thank u @Rudi I tried with 7-zip for extracting the omnetpp bundle. In the first step when we click on mingwenv.cmd and it will start extracting all the files in win64 but at the end it is showing message as **win64/mingw64/bin/qtbinpatcher.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file** .Also i tried by disabling my system antivirus protection.

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. qtbinpatcher.exe is clearly part of the .7z file that is extracted. Why it is not found is beyond me. Is that file present in `tools/win64/mingw64/bin` ? Or probably it's an other error like out of disk space or some permission error?

Answer (score 0):

`run ./configure WITH_QTENV = no`

Comment: While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.